# How do I get like to return data from multiple tables?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to modify the following query to return data from multiple tables.

I have the main contacts table where all contact details are stored. Companies are also stored in the Contacts table. Companies are mapped to Contacts in a join table named CompanyPersonMap.

I also have an attributes table where the contacts are assigned certain attributes, possibly many per contact.

Now, I want to return all the contacts that have a certain attribute assigned PLUS the person's Company name and address found in a different row in the Contacts table.

This code works but only returns the contactId. Fine for what I needed but I can't figure out how to modify it for the above requirement.

```
var peopleAndAddresses = Contacts.Where(c => c.AssignedAttributes
.Any (aa => aa.AttributeID == 1153))
.Select(x => x.ContactID);
```

Any suggestions for doing this?

Thanks!

Edit-

I tried working on the .Select() statement and found the path from the contact to its organzation via the PersonOrgMap table. Unfortunately, I can't get any of the data about the organization. I tried .Any(), .All(), and .FirstOrDefault(). Any suggestions?

.Select (c => new {c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.PersonOrgMap.FirstOrDefault (pom => pom.ChildContactID) })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below will get you all Contacts that have at least one AssignedAttribute with an AttributeID of 1153. I think this is what you're looking for.

```
var peopleAndAddress = Contacts
   .Where(c => c.AssignedAttributes.Any(aa => aa.AttributeID == 1153))
   .Select(c => c);
```

However, your statement "name and address found in a different row in the Contacts table" makes me think that this might not be what you need. Can you just get what the Company Name and Address is from properties on Contact?

Comment: No, I don't see how I can get to the company and company address info.

Comment: I think I understand now. A Contact can be a person or a company, is that correct? Also, are you using EF or LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: Yes, a contact can be a company or a person. We are using ef4.

Comment: Ok, then the Contact entity should have some sort of navigation property to another Contact that represents the company.